# SQL SELECT WHERE NAME IS ALMOST SIMILAR TO A STRING

Tags: mysql, select

I want to implement a search functionality, that returns records that are almost similar to the user's input. For example, if a user types the word "COMUTER". If there are fields with values like "COMPUTER, COMPUTERS, COMPUTE, COMPUTED" Should be returned in the results.
I am using MySQL database.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not the kind of question that's answered on Stack Overflow. That said, you want to look into "Natural Language Full-Text Searches" and/or the Levenshtein distance between words. When you *do* have a reference implementation, you'll be welcome asking questions about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql supports text based searching.

Create a `fulltext` index over the columns you want to search:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable  
ADD FULLTEXT(col1, col2, …)
```

Then to query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE MATCH (col1, col2, …)
AGAINST ('COMUTER' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```